# Use XMLHttpRequest to post data tback to webserver with parameters

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

The below code works find if I remove the string parameter from the **PostUser** method.
But when I add **blob** it fails with 404. What am I doing wrong?

> controller

```
public class LongPollController : ApiController
{
    public User PostUser(string blob)
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            Name = "John Smith",
            Age = 20,
        };

        return user;
    }
}
```

> cshtml

```
<div id="message">Waiting....</div>

@section scripts {
<script>
    var data = new Object();
    data.blob = 'Hello World';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            handleUser(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
        }
    };
    request.open("POST", "api/longpoll/user");
    request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.send(JSON.stringify(data));

    function handleUser(user) {
        var msg = document.getElementById('message');
        msg.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + user.Name + '<br />' +
            'Age: ' + user.Age + '<br />'
    }

</script>
```

What is the correct way to add my data to the **request.send()** such that WebApi picks them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web api is a bit different then asp.net mvc controllers and Web api default mapper is a bit different too. 
1. create c# class to hold input to web api

```
public class JsData{
public string Blob{get;set;}
}
```

2. change

```
public User PostUser(string blob)
```

to

```
public User PostUser(JsData input)
```

In you case its also possible to run, but then you need to modify routing for web.api

Comment: But what if I want to put other methods on the longpoll controller?

Comment: I tested your suggest changes, I still go a 404.

Comment: It worked with the model as a parameter. I didn't have to change PostUser to Post or change the request uri. By default the WebApi route is controller/{x}Action where {x} is the method (_i.e. GET POST PUT DELETE_) thanks

Comment: This works for me, but if i just wanted a plain string argument is that possible, sending a string? Or do I have to use the overload of **request.open()** that takes document data?

Comment: @user1515024 with just string you can probably use [FromBody] before parameter attribute and it should map

Comment: No it didn't, but I can use the data object since that is working fine for me.